# Creating a pandas Dataframe from a matrix of occurrences and a list of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have an occurrences DataFrame :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,3,size=(4,3)))

Out[0] :
    0   1   2
0   2   2   1
1   2   2   2
2   1   1   1
3   2   1   2
```

and a list of values :

```
L = np.random.random_integers(10,15,size=df.values.sum())

Out[1] : 
array([13, 11, 15, 11, 15, 13, 12, 11, 12, 15, 11, 11, 10, 11, 13, 11, 14,
       10, 12])
```

I need your assistance for creating a new DataFrame of the same size than df which has the values of the list L given the occurrences matrix df :

```
    0           1            2
0   [13, 11]    [15, 11]    [15]
1   [13, 12]    [11, 12]    [15, 11]
2   [11]        [10]        [11]
3   [13, 11]    [14]        [10, 12]
```

Comment: How about you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Simple nested loop variant:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,3,size=(4,3)))

L = np.random.random_integers(10,15,size=df.values.sum())

new_df = df.astype(object).copy()
L_ind = 0
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        new_df.loc[i, j] =  list(L[L_ind: L_ind + df.iloc[i, j]])
        L_ind += df.iloc[i, j]
```

df:

```
   0  1  2
0  2  2  1
1  1  1  2
2  1  2  2
3  2  2  2
```

L:

```
array([15, 12, 10, 12, 13, 15, 13, 13, 15, 13, 15, 15, 12, 11, 14, 11, 10,
       15, 15, 13])
```

new_df:

```
          0         1         2
0  [15, 12]  [10, 12]      [13]
1      [15]      [13]  [13, 15]
2      [13]  [15, 15]  [12, 11]
3  [14, 11]  [10, 15]  [15, 13]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution works well. Is there a shorter solution using df.applymap, or some similar functions ?

Answer (score 0):

this code might help

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(7)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,3,size=(4,3)))
# print df

L = np.random.random_integers(10,15,size=df.values.sum())
currentIndex=0
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for c in df.columns.tolist():
    new_list = []
    for val in df[c]:
        small_list = []
        for i in range(val):
            small_list.append(L[currentIndex])
            currentIndex+=1
        new_list.append(small_list)
    new_df.insert(c,c,new_list)

print new_df
```

new_df

```
0         1         2
0  [10, 11]      [14]  [14, 15]
1      [12]  [10, 13]  [10, 10]
2  [12, 10]  [12, 13]      [15]
3  [14, 10]      [14]  [10, 13]
```